# Child Hover not returning to unhovered state

Tags: css, class, hover

I am trying to construct a chunk of code that is an image and a text caption, which is a single anchor. the image is an image tag and the text is in a DIV tag.

When the anchor is hovered, the image+text box has a border appear, and the text div transitions between text to then show the background image (using opacity 1 to 0)

USING CSS ONLY

My issue is that I can't seem to find the best CSS to write this code, what I have is:

HTML:

```
<div class="outerCCBox">
<a href="*url*" >
    <img src="images/logo/clarityTeeth.png" alt="">
    <div class="clarityUnderBox">
        <div class="clarityBox">
        Clarity Makeup
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

The "clarityUnderBox is a presized box containing the background image that appears when the covering text fades out on hovering over the anchor tag.

CSS:

```
  .clarityUnderBox {
        width:256px !important;
        height:86px !important;
        background:url('../../images/logo/Clarity-C-320.png') no-repeat;
        background-size:contain;
    }

    .clarityBox {
        width:100% !important;
        height:100% !important;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity:1;
        color:#f0f0f0;
        transition:  color 0.4s linear,opacity 0.6s;
    }
```

All CSS is simplified for this question (fonts, transition -types- etc removed). 
The issue I am having appears to be with the next piece of code, the "hover" element:

```
.outerCCBox a:hover > .clarityUnderBox .clarityBox  {
    opacity:0;
    color:transparent;
    }
```

EDITED CSS:
originally

```
.outerCCBox a:hover .clarityUnderBox .clarityBox {
opacity:0;
color:transparent;
}
```

which behaves in the same way, as with the ">" selector.

The issue is that the hover works fine when hovering over the anchor element but when moving away, the .clarityBox class doesn't return to it's pre-hover state.

1) How do I make this return to it's pre hover state?
1b) Do I need to make a separate ~ a:not-on-hover CSS declaration?

2) How can I tidy up and make the "hover" CSS line more specific? - the way I've done it above works, but I'm sure there's a better syntax to it. I have tried things like using "*" and ">" selectors with limited success (combined with some rearrangement of class orders in the HTML)

Thanks for your guidance.

**EDIT**:
As requested, a fuller fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gwrrezys/9/

But this fiddle doesn't show the image above the text, but it does replicate the general issue with the hover not updating / or not returning to its original state.

cheers

**SOLUTION**:

As suggested in comments by Martin, making the anchor a block element fixed this issue, I have retained the issue in the jsFiddle for reference and can be found by repeatedly hovering and then hovering off the anchor area.

Comment: You put a lot of work into the question; upvoted. But please also create a jsfiddle so that we can tinker with it.

Comment: I can’t figure out what your actual problem is here.

Comment: `.clarityCCBox a:hover .clarityUnderBox .clarityBox` what you are exactly selecting with this.

Comment: your code seems to work well http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/sz5b4jre/. other than removing the `!important` declarations, I don't see any major improvements.

Comment: @Atal I am trying to change the properties of the .clarityBox div when the outer parent anchor tag is hovered over. I have changed it to use the ">" selector which is something I'd also previously tried but found the same issue that the page didn't sense when hover was no longer active.

Comment: @Martin I am not sure I understand what your problem is anymore ... maybe you want the anchor to be `display: inline-block` or `block` to actually surround the children? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/sz5b4jre/2/) ... so the hover area does not extend outside of it ... and is contained in the anchors flow

Comment: Thanks web-tiki, I think the issue may be my surrounding CSS then - somehow - I have added a full jsfiddle, and linked it into the original question. 

And Martin, thanks for your help, I will try now with the anchor a block element. Hopefully the fiddle edit on my original post will show the issue better.

Comment: Thank you Martin, by making the Anchor tag a Block element fixed it entirely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual problem is with the hovered parent (your anchor element) not having a `width` set.
If you make the anchor a block element it will fix the "leaking" content issue. by either

1. making the anchor `display: block` with set `width` and `height`
2. or making the parent fit the content by making it `display: inline-block`

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/sz5b4jre/2/)

---

**General to displaying children on hovered parents:**

As soon as you extend a child of a `:hover` element over the **whole screen** (100% width and height) the parent will stay in the hovered state as long as you are hovering over the child.

To get around that you need to **break the child out of its parents flow** ... for example by making it's **`position: fixed`** (or `position: absolute` if the parent has no `position: relative`).

For example by using something like this on the child - and the **`z-index: -1;`** here makes sure it moves behind the parent:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top:0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/43ngw9Lu/)

Or (depending on what area exactly you wan to cover with the child) you can alternatively extend the child only over a particular hover area (e.g. its parent) ... here you would then use **`position:absolute`** on the child and **`position: relative`** on the parent (to make sure you **keep the child in the parents flow**).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/43ngw9Lu/1)

---

<sup>A quick read on positioning elements: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/</sup>

Comment: I have tried this with positions relative, absolute and fixed and this doesn't make any changes to the original problem. I have also removed the width/height 100% but then the text and black background do not cover the background image they need to cover so this isn't an option. And doesn't seem to fix the original problem either.

the width:100%/height:100% doesn't appear to - as you say - take up the entire screen. This element is contained within the .outerCCBox element

Comment: I added a comment to your question (suggesting to make the anchor a [**block element** to enclose the children](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/sz5b4jre/2/))... does that go more in the right direction? If yes ... then I will edit the answer to accomodate for that =)